# Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

Does anyone know how to do a listview which looks like this? I'm interesting in the style of rows with an own background and the selector working fine.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's the notification screen. Do you want to have notifications shown there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really rather unclear what you are looking for.

In each main row, the text are `TextViews`, the image is an `ImageView`, and they are positioned probably via a `RelativeLayout`.

The header rows are a `TextView`.

The rows are intermingled via some sort of adapter, like for any `ListView`. You could use my `SackOfViewsAdapter` or `MergeAdapter` for that, or you could create your own subclass of `BaseAdapter`. The adapter will indicate which rows are enabled and which are not, to determine which can be clicked or selected.

In the future, please consider asking more concrete questions.

Comment: I'll try to be more concrete.
In the attached image there is a ListView. What i want is to have the rows with a specific background (from a drawable for example) and the selector working fine. 
When i define in my layout myrow.xml and i select a background por each row, the selector or the highlight onclick doesn't work. But i think that there should be a way to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: If would follow your suggestion of SackOfViewsAdapter would I provide this to a ListView or would I need to do and AbsListView or similiar?